# Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11 Processing triggers for fontconfig (2.11.0-0ubuntu4.2)

Tags: 14.04, xorg, lightdm, dbus

I was installing lightdm using the command `mona@pascal:~$ sudo apt-get install gnome` for Ubuntu 14.04 and received the following warning. Installation is still going on. Should I care and if yes, how to fix?

```
(gconftool-2:19650): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
Processing triggers for fontconfig (2.11.0-0ubuntu4.2) ...
```